# Wordpress custom link for every user

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

How can i create a page without creating an actual page? I want to create websitelink.com/username where username will be the username of every user on my site. I want a profile page of every user and they can view other profile too. User dont have admin privileged. Thank you. I dont want to use plugin because I need to customize the view. I also want to view user profile even not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom page template and then write a code to get user by username. So your link will be like websitelink/users/{username} username will be dynamic.

```
    <?php
    /**
    * Template Name: User Profile Page
    **/

    // Getting the username from the url
    $link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $link_array = explode('/',$link);
    $loginname = end($link_array);

    // Getting user info by wordpress default function
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($loginname);
    if($user){
      echo $user;
    }
```

$user will have all the info which you will need.

Comment: Hi kunal I tried your code but it giving me 404 not found page.

Comment: Have you created page with "User Profile Page" template in admin area?

Comment: Yes I created a profile page then use the custom profile page template that you give to me but still it is not showing the user that I echo it is showing page not found.

Comment: You are missing some thing, please check the url which is generated while creating a page if error still occurs then you can create url like  websitelink/users/?username=xyz